# Switch complex WinForms app to WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, refactoring, wpf, mvvm

This question is connected with my older question [C# Application GUI design dependent on configuration](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/300395/c-application-gui-design-dependent-on-configuration).

> I have built quite big WinForms application working in industry for a few years. It communicates with many HW devices. Application can be configured to use or not use some of these devices and GUI is modified by this configuration. Now, even more devices (and application possible configurations) are going to be added, so I need to refactor whole application, maybe even write the most of it again and it will be very painful work as it was generally my the first bigger project.

Finally, I decided to start learning WPF and I'm going to rewrite this application again using WPF, partly because I feel that such complex WinForms application isn't easily extensible and maintainable, partly because I want to learn WPF anyway in the future.

I want to use it properly and separate business logic from UI. I came across some MVVM tutorials using WPF, but all of them are very simple. My application has quite complex menus, few `DataGridViews`, and `PixtureBox`, which I'm drawing some measured 2-D stuff onto.
As I said, application communicates a lot with several devices as well as  with SQL server both-sided, and of course it has many threads. Also, there is quite a lot of miscellaneous dialogs.
At this moment in WinForms version, it's mess of logic and UI mixed together.

Can you suggest me any approach, how to start separating logic from UI in such kind of complex project?

I've read many WPF/MVVM tutorials, but all examples are simple, of course, and I'm not able to think in MVVM enough yet.

Comment: In the same boat, I started with some WPF MVVM projects, like a menu tree to add navigation to new system. Then started with a single set of screen for path of the nav. I am not the lead so I don't work on this regularly, but it is how "I got my feet wet" Not looking forward to converting one of my own projects, its a big undertaking. I started with this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

Comment: It seems very difficult to keep the project dedicated to MVVM, be careful as you lose the benefits when the project starts to migrate away from MVVM  in order to maintain functionality that you have not yet learned to code in true MVVM.

Comment: WPF is complex enough where I believe you need a book and some videos to learn it properly.  Web tutorials alone are not going to be sufficient.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I'm reading this book `WPF in Action with Visual Studio 2008`.  It's very nice book, but rather about WPF itself. For the next time, I'm going to read `Windows Presentation Foundation 4.5 Cookbook` book, which offers full examples and I hope that it will be nice training how to use my WPF knowledge acquired in the first book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same approach as with any other major refactoring.

1. Built unit tests to validate the behavior of the existing code.
2. Identify and isolate small sections of code that can be refactored.
3. Refactor one section at a time.
4. Verify that all unit tests (see step 1) continue to pass.  If they fail, fix your refactoring.
5. Rinse and repeat until you regret the day you ever decided to refactor the code base.
6. Eventually you'll complete the refactoring.  Swear off code-behind and promise yourself that you'll never, ever make those mistakes again.

---

As far as how to separate out business logic from UI logic within MVVM.  For the most part, all of your business logic should live at your Model layer or lower.  All UI related logic, including properties to be bound to, will live at the View and ViewModel layer.

A good rule of thumb on "Is it business logic or UI logic" is the following.  If the behavior of the code should persist regardless of what the UI is, that's business logic.  If the code's behavior is tied to the presentation of the data, that's UI logic.

Comment: *If the code's behavior is tied to the presentation of the data,*  Warning Will Robinson! **This is business logic:**  "Disable buttonX if A and B is entered". The *business class* should expose a boolean for that, and/or perhaps an event.  **This is UI logic:** If buttonX is disabled, disable textBoxX". And even that *might* not be UI logic if the requirement is:  "if A and B is entered then X must not have a value." **Maybe we should say** "if BO state changes because of UI state change, that's wrong."

Comment: Thank you. I should start learning Unit Testing, this general approach seems very reasonable.